# How to fix error with GridSearchCV in Python?

Tags: python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score  
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit


x=[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5,4,7,10,18,6,8]
y=[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]
train_date,test_date,train_y,test_y=train_test_split(          
x,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)

print(train_date)
classifier=SGDClassifier(random_state=0)
f=classifier.get_params().keys()
print(f)
parameters_grid={'loss':['hinge','log','squared_hige', 
'squared_loss'],'penalty':['l1','L2'],'n_iter':range(5, 10), 'alpha': 
np.linspace(0.0001,0.001, num=5)}
cv=StratifiedShuffleSplit(train_y,  n_iter=10, test_size=0.2, 
random_state=0)
grid_cv=GridSearchCV(classifier, parameters_grid, scoring='f1_micro', 
cv=cv)
grid_cv.fit(train_date,train_y)
a=grid_cv.grid_score_
print(a)
```

1) TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_iter'
    2) 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: `n_iter` is a parameter name that has changed to `n_splits` in recent versions. You'd have to replace `n_iter` by `n_splits` for that to work. As for the second error, a stack trace is necessary

Comment: I replaced n_iter by n_splits but  the error occurred: cv=StratifiedShuffleSplit(train_y, n_splits=range(5, 10), test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'n_splits'

Comment: The error is direct and right - `n_splits` is meant to be *one single integer*, not a range. You're passing `range(5, 10)` to a parameter that is meant to receive a single integer.